# ExactTarget subscribe form also sends form detail

Tags: php, forms, email, exacttarget

Currently have a newsletter subscribe form that submits info to a an ExactTarget account.
Is it possible to have the same form send an email, similar to a PHP contact form?
At one time this was a PHP form.

I did review Denver's MailChimp Subscribe in Contact Form option:
[Mail Chimp Subscribe In Contact Form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12792645/mail-chimp-subscribe-in-contact-form)

This form does not need a check box to subscribe to the newsletter.

```
<form action="http://cl.exct.net/subscribe.aspx?lid=hidden" name="subscribeForm" method="post">  
<input type="hidden" name="thx" value="enewsletter-thank-you.php" />  
<input type="hidden" name="err" value="enewsletter-error.php" />  
<input type="hidden" name="MID" value="hidden" />

<ul class="contactForm">    
<li class="contactForm">
<label class="formFieldQuestion">E-mail Address:&nbsp;<span class="redrequired">*</span></label>
<input class="field-text" type="text" name="Email Address" size="20" value=""></li> 

<li class="contactForm">
<label class="formFieldQuestion">Full Name:</label>
<input class="field-text" type="text" name="Full Name" size="20" value=""></li>

<li class="contactForm">
<label class="formFieldQuestion">Company:</label>
<input class="field-text" type="text" name="Company or Organization" size="20" value=""></li>

<li style="padding-left:10px;">
<input id="saveForm" class="button_form" type="submit" value="Subscribe" name="submit"> </li>

</ul>
</form>
```

Comment: Forgot to note that the email would include the same info as the subscribe fields.

Comment: You could add a ajax call on submit that post the data to the contact post url.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can send this as a curl request. Change your form action to something like `mail_and_submit.php`.

Then, in `mail_and_submit.php`:

```
//extract data from the post
extract($_POST);

//set POST variables
$url = 'http://cl.exct.net/subscribe.aspx?lid=hidden';
$fields = array(
            'thx' => urlencode($thx),
            'error' => urlencode($error),
            'MID' => urlencode($MID),
... (etc)
);

//url-ify the data for the POST
foreach($fields as $key=>$value) { $fields_string .= $key.'='.$value.'&'; }
rtrim($fields_string, '&');

//open connection
$ch = curl_init();

//set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, count($fields));
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);

//execute post
$result = curl_exec($ch);

//close connection
curl_close($ch);
```

THEN, build the email message with those same fields, and send, with something like:

```
$message = 'A post was submitted:<br/>';
$message .= 'thx: ' . $thx;
$message .= 'error: ' . $error;
$message .= 'MID: ' . $mid;
```

... etc, then mail with:

```
mail('some-email@address.com', 'Your Entry', $message);
```

Comment: the MID, thx and error is hidden values for Exact Target to process, is there a way to send this data thru cURL? Also, the thx and error is redirects to confirm the user is subscribed or an error happened in the processing.

Comment: the cURL works but Exact Target is not like the form data submitted, trying to take this Ajax call and change it to submit the data: [link]https://gist.github.com/3841680

Comment: Then you can use jquery to do the ajax, build out your post variables with something like `$.post("http://cl.exct.net/subscribe.aspx?lid=hidden", $("#subscribeForm").serialize());`